# Coprime Symmetric Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

We define two $ n\times n $ matrices $ c,d \in M_{n}(\mathbb{Z}) $ to be co-prime if
$$\{\gamma \in M_{n}(\mathbb{Q})|\gamma c,\gamma d \in M_{n}(\mathbb{Z})\} = M_{n}(\mathbb{Z}) .$$
We also define a pair of matrices $ (c,d) $ to be a symmetric pair if
$$cd^{T} = dc^{T} .$$
We define an equivalence relation $ \sim $ on the set of all coprime pairs of symmetric matrices by
$$ (c,d) \sim (c',d') \textit{ if there exists } u \in \textit{SL}_{n}(\mathbb{Z}) \textit{ such that } (c,d) = (uc',ud') ,$$
and set $ \Delta $ equal to the set of all equivalence classes. Now the paper I'm reading makes the following claim:

The set
$$\{(c,d) \in \Delta:|c| \neq 0\} $$
is in bijective correspondence with the set
$$ \{a\in M_{n}(\mathbb{Q}|a^{T} = a\} $$
via the prescription $ (c,d) \mapsto c^{-1}d $.
The paper claims this is a well known result however I am am not aware of this result. Does anybody know the name of this result, or where I might find a proof. I get this impression that this is from a paper of Siegel's, however I am neither able to read German, nor get a copy quickly.

As usual any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original question as is stated is FALSE.

If you replace $SL_n(\mathbb Z)$ with $GL_n(\mathbb Z)$ in the equivalence relation, then it is true. Alternatively you may use the set $\{(c,d)\in\Delta:\  \det(c)>0\}$ instead of $\{(c,d)\in\Delta:\ \det(c)\neq 0\}$.

Here a proof.

First, let me note that if $d=I$ is the identity matrix, then any matrix $c$ is coprime with $I$ and for any symmetric $c$, the pair $(c,d)$ is coprime and symmetric.

Since the OP uses $c^{-1}$ I suppose that $c$ is invertible.

Let call $F$ the map $F(c,d)=c^{-1}d$. We need to check that

1) $F$ is well defined on equivalence classes

2) The image of $F$ is in the set of symmetric matrices

3) $F$ is injective

4) $F$ is surjective on the set of symmetric matrices.

We see 1). Clearly if $a=uc$ and $b=ud$ then $$F(a,b)=a^{-1}b=c^{-1}u^{-1}ud=c^{-1}d=F(c,d).$$

Wee see 2). If $dc^T=cd^T$ then 
$$c^{-1}dc^{T}=d^T$$ whence, since $(c^T)^{-1}=(c^{-1})^T$,
$$c^{-1}d=d^T(c^{T})^{-1}=d^T(c^{-1})^T=(c^{-1}d)^T$$

So $F(c,d)$ is symmetric.

We see $3)$. Suppose that $F(c,d)=F(a,b)$. Then 
$$c^{-1}d=a^{-1}b\qquad b=ac^{-1}d\qquad a=ac^{-1}c$$
thus, setting $u=ac^{-1}$ we see that $$(a,b)=(uc,ud)\qquad (u^{-1}a,u^{-1}b)=(c,d)$$

Since $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ are both coprime pairs, this forces both $u$ and $u^{-1}$ to belong to $M_n(\mathbb Z)$. Therefore $u\in GL_n(\mathbb Z)$ and $\det(u)=\pm1$.

Thus $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ are in the same $GL_n(\mathbb Z)$-equivalence class. Note that if we restrict to the set of comprime symmetric pairs $(x,y)$ where $\det x>0$ then we have $\det u=\det a\det c^{-1}>0$, hence $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ are in the same $SL_n(\mathbb Z)$-equivalente class.

We see $4)$. If $a$ is symmetric, then we can write 
$$a=\dfrac{1}{n}d$$ where $d$ has integers coefficients and $n$ is the minimum common denominator of its coefficents (set $n=1$ if $d=0$). Thus, setting $c=nId$ we have $a=c^{-1}d=F(c,d)$. Clearly $(c,d)$ is coprime by the choice of $n$, and symmetric beacuse $a$ is symmetric, so $d$ is, $c$ is a multiple of $Id$ so it is symmetric and commutes with any matrix.

**Counterexample to the original question.**

If $n=2k+1$ then the $-Id\in GL_n(\mathbb Z)$ but not in $SL_n(\mathbb Z)$.

Thus, given any symmetric coprime pairs $(c,d)$ we have that $(-c,-d)$ is not equivivalent to $(c,d)$, however $F(c,d)=F(-c,-d)$. This shows that the correspondence is not a bijection.

If $n$ is $2k$ than consider the block diagonal matrix
$u=\begin{pmatrix}U& & & \\& I & & \\ & & \ddots & \\ & & & I\end{pmatrix}$ where 
$U=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$ and $I=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$

Then, given any symmetric coprime pair $(c,d)$ the pair $(uc,ud)$ is symmetric and coprime (note that $u^{-1}=u=u^{T}$). 
However, $u\in GL_n(\mathbb Z)$ but $\det u=-1$ so $u$ is not in $SL_n(\mathbb Z)$. It there is $M\in GL_n(\mathbb Z)$ such that $(Muc,Mud)=(c,d)$ then, since $c$ is invertible we would have $Mu=Id$ and thus $1=\det M\det u=-\det M$. This shows that $(uc,ud)$ is not equivalent to $(c,d)$. However, $F(uc,ud)=F(c,d)$.

In conclusion, the set $\{(c,d)\in\Delta \det c\neq 0\}$ is NOT in bijection with the set $\{a\in M_n(\mathbb Q): a^T=a\}$.

Comment: I'm just about to go to lunch so I haven't had the chance to read through this thoroughly yet. However at a glance it appears that you have assumed $ d $ is invertible. I'm not aware that this is necessarily the case. Thank you for your help though. I'll give it a proper read when I get back.

Comment: So I've read this through, and as I said before I see no justification for the assumption that $ d^{-1} $ exists. In the definitions it is specified that only $ c $ has non-zero determinant. Could you please elaborate on this.

Comment: Ok, but $c$ is supposed to be invertible or not?

Comment: $ c $ is invertible, however $ d $ may not be.

Comment: Ok, I edited, if $c$ is invertbile but $d$ may be not, then by changing bijection (and the equivalence relation) the proof goes fine. Are you sure of the orders of multiplications?

Comment: The definitions I wrote above are certainly the way he defines it in the paper, however I am starting to wonder whether a step between the definitions and the claim might have switched the orders. I'll have a check.

Comment: You called it correct. I just went over the some of the introductory comments. The guy writing the paper denotes the transpose of a matrix $ A $ by $ \textit{ }^{T}A $ rather than $ A^{T} $. So when written $ c^{T}d = d^{T}c $ it leads to confusion (or at least it lead to my confusion). Taking this into account your solution will probably work through completley correct.

Comment: Ok, I re-edited the answer, now everything is coherent.

Comment: @cfairwea why did you unaccepted the answer after having accepted it? Is there some mathematical prolem? I think we agreed that with the right order of multiplication the answer is completely correct...

Comment: I realised that injectivity isn't proven. In particular it isn't clear that $ ac^{-1} $ is of determinant $ 1 $.

Comment: @cfairwea $ac^{-1}$ is a matrix with integer entries and invertible, in particular its determinant is an invertible integer, thus it is $\pm 1$. Of course $F(-c,-d)=F(c,d)$, and if $n$ is odd then in this case $F$ is not injective. Are you sure that the equivalence relation requires $u\in SL(\mathbb Z)$ and not in $GL(\mathbb Z)$?  The above example shows that the claim is false if you require $\det u=1$, while it is proven if the requirement is $|\det u|=1$

Comment: The equivalence relation definitely requires $ u $ to be in $ \textit{SL}_{n}(\mathbb{Z}) $. When we say $ ac^{-1} $ is invertible we simply mean that it's determinant is non-zero, i.e it's inverse is defined. We are not considering it as an element of a group. Thus invertibility does not imply determinant $ \pm 1 $. With regards to $ n $ being odd or even, as $ F $ is defined on the set of equvalence classes $ (-c,-d) \sim (c,d) $, your above example is not a contradiction, these are the same element.

Comment: @cfairwea if $A$ is invertible then $\det(A)\det(A^{-1})=\det(AA^{-1})=1$ whence, if $\det A\in \mathbb Z$, $\det A=\pm1$.

Comment: @cfairwea $(-c,-d)\sim(c,d)$ only if the equivalence relation is defined with $u\in GL_n(\mathbb Z)$ because $\det (-Id)=(-1)^{n}$, hence if $n=2k+1$ we have $\det(-Id)=-1$, so $(-c,-d)$ is not equivalent to $(c,d)$

Comment: @cfairwea may be the confusion is the following. Let $u=ac^{-1}$. A priori we know only that $u\in GL_n(\mathbb Q)$. But both $uc,ud$ are in $M_n(\mathbb Z)$. Since $(c,d)$ are coprime this forces $ u\in M_n(\mathbb Z)$. So $u\in GL_n(\mathbb Z)$.

Comment: Ah of course, we have that $ ac^{-1}d = b $.

Comment: Let $u=\begin{pmatrix} 0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$, then $u=u^{-1}$ and $\det u=-1$. We have $F(uc,ud)=F(c,d)$. So if the relation requires $u\in SL_n(\mathbb Z)$ I think that $F$ is never injective. (Also for $n$ even).

Comment: Wait this comes back to the fact that we have claimed $ u $ is in $ \textit{SL}_{n}(\mathbb{Z}) $. We have claimed above that because $ u \in \textit{GL}_{n}(\mathbb{Q})\cap M_{n}(\mathbb{Z}) $ we must have that $ u \in \textit{SL}_{n}(\mathbb{Z}) $. But this is not the case.

Comment: Not exactly. $u\in GL_n(\mathbb Q)\cap M_n(\mathbb Z)$ implies $u\in GL_n(\mathbb Z)$, thus $\det u=\pm1$. In particular, the proof given in the answer plus the two examples above show that the claim is true if the equivalence relation is with $u\in GL_n(\mathbb Z)$ and false in general if we require $u\in SL_n(\mathbb Z)$. If we want to keep $u\in SL_n(\mathbb Z)$ then we must add some other hypothesis: For instance the requirement  $\det c>0$ instead $\det c\neq 0$ would also solve the problem because in this case $\det (ac^{-1})$ would be positive, and hence the case $-1$ is excluded.

Comment: I think until injectivity is sorted I will have to unaccept this answer again. Your argument about $ \textit{GL}_{n}(\mathbb{Z}) $ is definitley flawed. For example $ \begin{pmatrix}
2 & 0\\
1 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix} $. This is in $ \textit{GL}_{n}(\mathbb{Q})\cap M_{n}(\mathbb{Z}) $. However $ u^{-1} \notin M_{n}(\mathbb{Z}) $, and so $ u \notin \textit{GL}_{n}(\mathbb{Z}) $.

Comment: the argument is: let $u=ac^1$. Then $u,u^{-1}$ which are a priori only in $M_n(\mathbb Q)$, are indeed in $M_n(\mathbb Z)$ because $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ are coprime and $(ua,ub)=(c,d)$ and $(u^{-1}c,u^{-1}d)=(a,b)$.

Comment: Once settled this, the problem that $u\in GL(\mathbb Z)$ remains. and the claim, as is stated is false.

Comment: I'm sorry, but you CANNOT prove injectivity for the original because it is simply FALSE. I edited the answer, giving a complete answer that cover two true statements with hypotheses modified with respect to the original formulation, and a complete counterexample to the original question. There is nothing more to say: the original question has a negative answer, if you want to turn that into a theorem you must modify hypothesis.